# Is it ok to down vote an answer because you disagree with something it said?

Tags: discussion, voting, answers

Is it ok to down vote an answer because you disagree with something it said?

I assumed it was, and that people were up voting because they agree with something it says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very question has been asked many times over. Some good answers can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236885/downvotes-are-primarily-opinion-based).

Ultimately, it is a fact of StackExchange that votes are often based on bias. They should, ideally, be based on how well the questions and answers meet the expectations towards posts here as expressed in the help center and this meta.

When speaking about extreme cases (both extremely good and extremely bad) the voting mechanism works reasonably well though, and arguably better than any conceivable alternative. It would work better if we had more active voters because the bias of few people can tip the scale quite heavily but that's just where we're at.

Comment: ha, thanks. I get it

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world, a well informed evaluation of a post would hinge on objective criteria of evaluation like:

- Does it answer the question?
- Is the response clear?
- Are there references and citations to appropriate sources?
- Are there factual errors?

In practice, many contributors to this site have radically different conceptions of philosophy and how to vote, and have difficulty distinguishing between what is accepted as a consensus in major philosophy communities, and what they believe philosophy should be. Hence, questions and answers that ask and answer questions about the [philosophy of sexuality (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/sexualit/), for instance, will be downvoted and closed, despite:

- The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy and other tertiary references having articles
- [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) having links to arguments
- [Philosophical books listed on Google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Sexuality/VYMYDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) which are obviously high-quality publications by professional philosophers.
- Citations from the sources above that are clear, and obviously answer a question.

So, the limp and flimsy voting that happens on this forum seems to often move along the lines of:

- I reject all answers but my own
- I don't like you
- You said something I diagree with
- I don't understand your answer, so you don't know what you're talking about
- I disagree with your Weltanschauung
- I hate Wikipedia and I'm really smart
- I read a philosophy book once and this doesn't make sense

This is evidenced particularly by the fact that much downvoting occurs without commentary, and often it's plain to see that people who disagree with you will frequently downvote your answers after being challenged.

There's a lot of knowledge on this site, and many knowledgeable people, but the calculus of upvoting and downvoting on this site is not governable by prescription or norms, plain and simple, and so strictly speaking if you confine your activity to voting, you are governed only by your conscience. The truth is if you were to use a d6 and downvote on 1, and upvote on all other outcomes, no one would know, and no one would stop you. Any representation to the contrary of this fact about this forum would be misguided.

Comment: there are a to of straw men there! I've asked how qualified you need to be to vote. not pretending to be anything but enthusiastic btw

Comment: @return A straw man is an argument that attacks a position that isn't held by an opponent. 1) There is no argument here, so none to attack. 2) My statement says "seems", and so I'm reporting a perception. 3) You asked after a normative position in the use of the voting mechanism, and I provided one, which while cynical, isn't far from the truth.  4) You used qualified 0 times in your question, nor did you touch any question of qualification. 5) You didn't scope "disagreement". 6) As you just had a post deleted for poor quality and foul language, pretenses would be silly. ; )

Comment: Welcome to PhilSE!

Comment: uhh, please don't be cute. yes, a vote is not an argument: so wy bother trying to reconstruct what it "means"? if you want, just add "no-one is as well lettered as me" and leave it

Comment: "An insubstantial concept, idea, endeavor or argument, particularly one deliberately set up to be weakly supported, e.g. by misrepresenting an opponent's argument by broadening or narrowing the scope of a premise, so that it can be easily knocked down; especially to impugn the strength of any related or contrasted thing or idea. " ?

Comment: it's amusing that you care more about the use of 'shit' than you do your own inaccuracies.

Comment: Why am I trying to reconstruct what your question means? It's one of three major approaches to philosophy. See [analytical philsophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy). Two other goals broadly are the pursuit of eudaimonia and making sense of life and the world through the development of a worldview rooted in spatiotemporal historicity.

Comment: You wander into a philosophy forum expecting your "meaning" to go without evaluation, it makes me wonder what exactly you're after. And I'll be cute as much as I want. Die Gedanken sind frei, und ich denke was ich will. ; )

Comment: Again, you have presented no argument, and I have attacked no argument, so there is no straw man. You asked a question, and I gave you my opinion. Distinctions of meaning matter.

Comment: sorry I'm a bit frayed rn. I think you've completely misunderstood me, I was talking about your unhelpful answer, not the question. and you've ignored the meaning of 'strawman' again. who cares... ; )

Comment: No, and no, and no. But it's okay you don't understand. Good luck with the fraying!

Comment: if you've not misunderstood me then you're just being deliberately obfuscating to "win an argument". so yes: no, no, and no

Comment: Again, there is no argument. There is only your perception of one.

Comment: Have a good day!

Comment: disagreement? ffs

Comment: stop trying to be technical. it's silly. this is meta, not your hobby horse for why you are better than others

Comment: "Left foot, right foot! What's the difference?!?" It's all technicalities and semantics. https://buffalonews.com/news/florida-suspends-fines-doctor-who-amputated-wrong-limb/article_6cb969fa-42b2-5883-a38b-9f55a6a3ceaf.html

Comment: Disagreement is not argumentation necessarily, and thus is a necessary but insufficient basis for evaluation. That's the point I'm making. Let it stew.

Comment: your first point was to respond to my claim you were using a straw man. you were using a straw man, according to the dictionary. I don't see the point in responding to the other FIVE points you made, unless you are able to admit you are wrong. such is the format

Comment: yes it's pretty facile. yes your answer is facile. why did you feel the need to make it? just delete. why anything you do?

Comment: and please stop winking and me and telling me to be OK it is pretty obvious that you are being passive aggressive in doing so, despite my admitting to being in a bad way rn

Comment: ok and sorry for raging slightly. hope you are well

Comment: This answer is perhaps an answer to a different question, but JD makes many good points. Users of the Philosophy stackexchange don't seem to use the voting system well. In part, that is probably because philosophy by its nature is often opinion based, so users are bound to disagree with answers no matter how good they are. For myself, I don't downvote an answer just because I don't agree with it, only if it contains a pretty serious error.

Comment: No need to apologize. You are free to express yourself as you see fit. And again, welcome to the site. :D

Comment: "This is evidenced particularly by the fact that much downvoting occurs without commentary" Lack of commentary on a downvote is not evidence of anything.